# Can not use class org.json.XML on Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to parse a XML String to JSON, I search and know that I can use library [java-json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) to do this. I added dependencies into build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hnib.docbaoonline"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

What I did :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = null;
try {
    jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(sampleXml);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON exception", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Android Studio notify me that I can not use XML class , I checked and found that I can not import package **org.json.XML**

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;  // error here
```

I do not know why, I also try by add jar file lib but have the same result.
Does anybody have the same problem and how to resolve ?

Comment: Could you show your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @MrNeo I edited my post, added snip code of dependencies.

Comment: This mean Android Studio not compile `json` library. Did you use under proxy? You could try add jar file into lib folder and add in Project Structure/dependencies.

Comment: post your complete build.gradle (module app)  file code

Comment: @ÅdəəlÅhmåd I added them , please help check it.

Comment: please check on your Android Studio, I can use other library normally except this library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the The **Project** view in you navigation, in your app/module's **libs** folder, where you have pasted your **.jar** File, right click on that .jar file and select **Add As Library** .

OR

In your build.gradle, add `compile files('libs/json-20150729.jar')` in 
**dependencies** block.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

    //This : 
    compile files('libs/json-20150729.jar')

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually a better way is to not use the jar in a libs folder since there is already a maven repo just follow the mave repo directions and include it directly

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20171018'
// use for newer gradle plugins
implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20171018'
```