# Can´t import class from updated org.json package

Tags: java, android, json, gradle

I have tried to use the `org.json.XML` class in my Android project. This class isn't provided by the core library's so I thought the only thing I had to do is use the updated `org.json` package with gradle. But I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to compile:

> error: cannot find symbol class XML

Here my MainActivity import:

```
...
import org.json.XML;
...
```

And my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'org.json:json:20160212'
...
}
```

I know that Android Studio is compiling the jar and that is working, but I want to know a way to get it working using the maven dependencies.

Comment: Have you checked out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050846/can-not-use-class-org-json-xml-on-android-studio

Comment: @BipinBhandari i want to know a way how to use the maven dependency instead of the jar

Comment: Did you clean the project, sync the gradle file, then try to build?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i also deleted the build folder

Comment: If you make a separate Gradle module in your app and add that as a dependency for that module, you can import it, but that's probably more work than you want to do (and it still won't import in the Android app code).

Comment: @cricket_007 this would change the package name for all json objects and arrays

Comment: No it wouldn't... It's too much to explain in the comments, but you are better off using an alternative library or just using the JAR file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use Jackson library to parse XML files.
Or if you want to keep doing it by yourself you can try using javax.XML

> http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/package-summary.html

instead of org.json.xml

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to convert a xml file to a json file

Comment: Jackson has the capability of working with both formats so you can easily do that

Answer (score 0):

This is maven dependency for `org.json.XML`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
```

Source: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212

Comment: OP is using Gradle and already has `'org.json:json:20160212'`

Comment: He says he wants to use maven in the comment above "i i want to know a way how to use the maven dependency instead of the jar"

Comment: when i try to compile it with gradle i can´t use the updated version i only get the version thats shipped with android.

Comment: If you click the Gradle tab in the Maven repository, then that is the correct way to include a dependency. There is no pom.xml to add the section that you copied